# Why INotifyPropertyChanged's event PropertyChangedEventHandler is always null?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

This is my sample code, why PropertyChangedEventHandler property is null?
the list is bounded to Listbox which should subscribe to the event. Shouldn't it?

```
public class Data<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
{
     T _data;

     public T MyData
     {
        get { return _data; }
        set 
        { 
            _data = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MyData");
         }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        var h = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
           h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
 }

   class Person
   {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public int Age { get; set; }
   }

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Data<Person>> list = new List<Data<Person>>();                   

    list.Add(new Data<Person> { MyData = new Person { Name = "Sam", Age = 21 } });
    list.Add(new Data<Person> { MyData = new Person { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 } });

    this.DataContext = list;
}
```

```
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listbox1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 Style="{DynamicResource lStyle}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Label Width="100" Content="{Binding Path=MyData.Name}"></Label>
                        <Label Width="100" Content="{Binding Path=MyData.Age}"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the listbox is being displayed but your event is still null?

Comment: @Gabe, the list is displayed fine, but  var h = this.PropertyChanged;  is null, why? How do I raise event

Comment: So `PropertyChanged` is still null, even after the list gets displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the ListBox hasn't had a chance to render and start listening for change events yet.

When I tested the following `PropertyChanged` was not null during the change inside `listbox1_MouseLeftButtonDown`.

```
Data<Person> p;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<Data<Person>> list = new List<Data<Person>>();
    this.p = new Data<Person> { MyData = new Person { Name = "Sam", Age = 21 } };
    list.Add(this.p);
    this.DataContext = list;
}

private void listbox1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    p.DataContext = null;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Are you saying that I can't bind it to data in Window's constructor?

Comment: @Mark You can bind in the constructor - the reason why the event is null is just because at the point where you are checking for null is before the first box has first rendered itself, and so it hasn't yet subscribed to the event.  I.e. the event being null is normal.

Comment: yeah, if I put this inside button's click event: 
`Person p = new Person { Name = "Andy", Age = 30 };
 list[0].MyData = p;` 
it works

Answer (score 0):

In your provided code, the PropertyChanged event handler will be subscribed to. Why do you think that is not the case?

Changes like this will update the listbox correctly:

```
List<Data<Person>> list = DataContext as List<Data<Person>>; 
list[0].MyData = new Person() { Name = "Bob", Age = 12 };
```

Remember that your Data class don't support property notify on individual properties,
so the following changes will not update the listbox.

```
List<Data<Person>> list = DataContext as List<Data<Person>>; 
list[0].MyData.Name = "Bob"; 
list[0].MyData.Age = 12;
```